# Controlling exponent length in formatted print

Tags: python, formatting, f-string

Test done with python 3.10

With `xx = 1.e-4`, I can have a nice print with `print ( np.format_float_scientific (xx, precision=0, exp_digits=1, unique=True, trim='-') )`. It prints `1e-4`, the result I want.

But this is a bunch of code for a rather simple task.

Can I control the length of the exponent with a formatted print ?

`print ( f'{xx:3.0e}' )` -> `1e-04`

`print ( '{:3.0e}'.format(xx) )` -> `1e-04`

Is there a way to have only one digit in the exponent ?

Olivier

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply replace the leading zero:

```py
xx = 1.0e-4
print(f"{xx:3.0e}".replace("e-0", "e-"))
```

Prints:

```
1e-4
```